# Mutability in fields for structs in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, mutability

I'm still new with Rust but I have doubts about how mutability works for fields in structs. Specifically how we can modify fields that originally were immutable. For example:

```
struct Point {
    x: isize,
    y: isize,
}

impl Point {
    fn new(x: isize, y: isize) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
    fn set_x(&mut self, new_x: isize) {
        self.x = new_x;
    }
}

struct Line {
    p: Point,
    q: Point,
}

impl Line {
    fn new(p: Point, q: Point) -> Self {
        Self { p, q }
    }
    fn set_x_in_p(&mut self, new_x: isize) {
        self.p.set_x(new_x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Both x and y are immutable
    let p = Point::new(0, 0);
    let q = Point::new(1, 1);

    // Line IS mutable
    let mut line = Line::new(p, q);

   // Modifying point p (originally immutable) with a new x 
    line.set_x_in_p(999);
}
```

Instead with references we cannot

```
   let x = 3;
   let y = &mut x; // does not work because x originally is immutable
```

So, how does it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `p` and `q` are indeed immutable, but then you move them into a `Line` instance with the constructor, since they're passed by value and don't implement `Copy` to enable implicit copying. This means that the original bindings (`p` and `q`) are no longer valid (the compiler will prevent you from using them) and the values are instead accessible only via the mutable `line` binding, which allows mutating its members. Essentially, it's not the *values* that are mutable, but rather their bindings. For example, the following code can be used to re-bind a value to change its mutability:

```
let x = String::from("hello world"); // using String as an example of a non-Copy type

let mut x = x; // this shadows the previous binding with a mutable one of the same name
x.make_ascii_uppercase(); // we can now mutate the string
let x = x; // shadow the mutable binding with an immutable one

println!("Result: {}", x);
```

This example works because we have direct control over the value, and can move/bind it as desired. Introducing references would limit what could be done - for example, the following examples wouldn't work:

```
let x = String::from("hello world");
let x_ref = &x; // create an immutable reference to x
let mut x_mut = x; // error - we can't move x while it's borrowed
let x_mut_ref = &mut x; // error - we can't create a mutable reference while any other references exist
```

I'd recommend reading the [ownership and moves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move.html) page of Rust by example, which explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring `x`, you are specifying it as immutable with the `let` instead of `let mut`.  When you then declare `y` and initialize it as `&mut x` you are attempting to borrow `x`. In Rust, the one thing you can never do is simultaneously have shared ownership AND mutability.

Check out [what Niko Matsakis has to say](https://youtu.be/jQOZX0xkrWA?t=1216) about ownership.